# Ignore \r vs \n differences with join command

Tags: bash, performance, list, shell, comparison

This is the command I'm using

```
join -1 1 -2 1 a-sorted.txt b-sorted.txt
```

I have a strong belief that the `\n` and `\r` differences at the end of the line is causing no results to show up, because I have entered in some duplicates between the lists to check, and join isn't finding them.

To be clear, I believe that one file may used `\n\r` at the end of each line and maybe the other uses `\r` at the end, so `foobar\n` is not the same as `foobar\n\r`, but I want it to be considered the same. I want white space to be ignored.

I'm using the solution from here: https://www.biostars.org/p/63016/

But I don't believe it took the variety of line breaks into consideration. How can I compare these 2 text lists for common rows, ignoring whitespace?

Comment: The easiest thing to do is preprocess your files so they all have the same unix-standard line-ending char `\n`. `dos2unix  a-sorted.txt b-sorted.txt ... multiple filenames ...` should be used before any unix cmd (`sort`, `uniq`, `join`). Good luck.

Comment: @shellter thanks so much! I ran that, and it flew through my list, which was O(n^2) before the sort and fix, in about 10 seconds! You saved my night!

Comment: Without modifing your files a-sorted.txt and b-sorted.txt: `join -1 1 -2 1 <(dos2unix < a-sorted.txt) <(dos2unix < b-sorted.txt)`

Answer (score 1):

You can ignore white-spaces or any special characters using `tr` bash utility. All you need to do is

```
join -1 1 -2 1 <(tr -d '\r' < a-sorted.txt) <(tr -d '\r' < b-sorted.txt)
```

doing so will remove carriage returns from both the files and pass them to `join` utility.